# Using AWS Parameter Store SecureStrings in CloudFormation user-data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I am trying to retrieve a SecureString from the Parameter Store to use in the user-data of a CloudFormation template.

I have tried various ways of doing this. but am struggling with the syntax of them all.

First of all I tried to use a map in the user-data as follows:

```
  UserData:  
    Fn::Base64: !Sub
      - |
        #!/bin/sh
        echo ${MySecureString} > /tmp/secureString.txt
      - MySecureString: {{resolve:ssm-secure:my-secure-string:1}}
```

I think that one resulted in a syntax error when loading the template via the console.

I've also tried:

```
  UserData:  
    Fn::Base64: !Sub
      - |
        #!/bin/sh
        echo ${MySecureString} > /tmp/secureString.txt
      - MySecureString: "{{resolve:ssm-secure:my-secure-string:1}}"
```

I think this one wrote the literal string "{{resolve:ssm-secure:my-secure-string:1}}" to the file.

I also tried moving this to a CFN parameter with the Parameter Store value as the default as follows:

MySecureString:
Type: String
Default: '{{resolve:ssm-secure:my-secure-string:1}}'

and in the EC2 resource:

```
  UserData:  
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/sh
      echo ${MySecureString} > /tmp/secureString.txt
```

Finally, I tried the simplest option

```
  UserData:  
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/sh
      echo {{resolve:ssm-secure:my-secure-string:1}} > /tmp/secureString.txt
```

but this also resulted in "{{resolve:ssm-secure:my-secure-string:1}}" being written to the file.

Are any of these approaches possible, and if so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad idea because you are storing the value of a secure parameter in an unsecured, and unencrypted, user-data string. Anyone with access to your AWS account will be able to view the value of the parameter by looking at the EC2 instance's user-data setting. It completely defeats the purpose of using SSM secure strings.

To do this in a secure manner, you should be giving the EC2 instance an IAM role that allows it to access the secret in SSM, and decrypt the secret with KMS. Then you could change your user-data to something like this:

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name my-secure-string --with-decryption > /tmp/secureString.txt
```

Where you would only need to put the name of the parameter in the user-data script.

Comment: Hi Mark, you are absolutely right, of course and you are quite right to highlight this strongly in answer to my question as I asked it to warm others to not do what I have suggested if the data is sensitive.. In this case, however, the string being stored does not really _need_ to be secure, it could just as easily be stored in a standard String in Parameter Store, but I just can't figure out the syntax to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I used a temporary SSM for the variables longer than 1000 characters and `Fn::ImportValue` for the short variables and keep security in place.

Once the `TmpLongSecureString` act as a `Resource` and has the SSM value, we are able to access it with `!GetAtt TmpLongSecureString.Value` in our recipe.

As for the `ShortString`, it's just an alternative and can be used either way, depending on the security policy required in the cluster.

```
Resources:
  TmpLongSecureString:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "/tmp/${ClusterStack}/TmpLongSecureString"
      Type: String
      Value: !Sub "{{resolve:ssm-secure:my-long-secure-string:1}}"

  UserData:  
    Fn::Base64: !Sub
      - |
        #!/bin/sh
        echo ${LongSecureString} > /tmp/LongSecureString.txt
        echo ${ShortString} > /tmp/ShortString.txt
        - LongSecureString: !GetAtt TmpLongSecureString.Value
          ShortString:
            Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub '${CustomStack}::MyShortString'
```